# i am creating two classes student(base) and detail.Why wont studen will access the variables roll_No ,class.?

Tags: python, inheritance

![enter image description here][1]i am creating two classes student(base) and detail .Detail is inheriting all the attributes of base .I am initializing the attributes (roll_no,name and class_stud)subclasses of base with students object of subclass created with student.**subclasses**().Here is the code:

```
student=type('student',(object,),{})       

def getinfo():  
    for studen in student.__subclasses__():
         studen.roll_no=input("enter the roll number")
         studen.name=input("enter the name of student")
         studen.class_stud=input("enter the class")


def printinfo():
     print('roll number ',roll_no,name,class_stud)

detail=type('detail',(student),{'info':getinfo(),'print':printinfo()})

ob=detail()
ob.info
ob.print
```

Comment: Unless you can explain why you use `type` instead of `class` and remove the obvious errors in the code, I don't think you can get anyone here to take you seriously.

Comment: According to my knowledge type(myclass) is same as class myclass.Rather class myclass is more traditional way of creating a class.As I am a beginner i would appreciate if you point out those errors..

Comment: It's not actually _the same_. For example, using a `class` definition gets you a scope with its own locals that you can define things inside of, which then becomes the dict of the class; if you're calling `type`, if you want the same thing, you have to do it manually, which is not exactly trivial (and clumsy even if you get it right). On the other hand, calling `type` allows you to pass in a dynamically-created set of attributes. But anyway, if you don't understand the differences, and have a good reason for needing `type`, use `class`.

Comment: Also, your `getinfo` function is adding class attributes to every subclass of `student` (which is to say, just the `detail` class), not adding instance attributes to every `student` instance, which is not at all what you said you were trying to do.

Comment: This is almost like you have read an Advanced Python book without reading a Beginning Python book

Comment: @cdarke: When I first learned Python, all I noticed was all the cool stuff deep under the covers that would allow me to do things that hadn't been possible in Tcl; it wasn't until a few months later that I noticed all the cool stuff above the covers that allowed me to do all the things I actually need to do every day that were possible in Tcl but a whole lot nicer in Python. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen anyone create Python classes this way, except to see if they could.  You have quite a few errors, but this might do what you want (although that is not clear):

```
student=type('student',(object,),{})

def getinfo(self):
    for studen in student.__subclasses__():
         studen.roll_no=input("enter the roll number: ")
         studen.name=input("enter the name of student: ")
         studen.class_stud=input("enter the class: ")

def printinfo(self):
     print('roll number ',self.roll_no,self.name,self.class_stud)

detail=type('detail',(student,),{'info':getinfo,'print':printinfo})

ob=detail()
ob.info()
ob.print()
```

As you can see, your main error was in not passing the object into the methods.  Other errors included a missing comma after student when defining detail.  See also comments by @abarnert.

This is a horrible way of defining a class in Python.

EDIT:
I have no idea why you are iterating over subclasses, this is probably what you meant for `getinfo`:

```
def getinfo(self):
    self.roll_no=input("enter the roll number: ")
    self.name=input("enter the name of student: ")
    self.class_stud=input("enter the class: ")
```

Comment: There _are_ good uses for creating classes this way—in particular, if you need to create a class dynamically. But when everything is statically available like this, it's just obfuscation.

Comment: Actually, I think the _biggest_ error was _calling_ `getinfo` and `printinfo` and passing the results as attributes of the new class, instead of passing the functions themselves. You seem to have fixed that unconsciously without even realizing it, while fixing his other errors. :)

Comment: @abarnert: I agree.  I forgot about those other fixes!

Comment: @cdarke Actually I am trying to access each attribute (roll_no, name and class_stud )through an object.I was thinking about giving the access to the values to other objects like studen1,2,3 and so on.                 Each student having its own roll_No ,name and class

Comment: @abarnert you mentioned in you previous comments that i was adding class attributes to subclasses rather than instance attributes .But in the solution provided by cdarke he has used class attributes,and it works fine.

Comment: @user18683: Well, when you have exactly one subclass and exactly one instance of that subclass, it probably seems to work out OK. But if you have more than one of either, it will not do what you want.